# How to work with organisation repo from PyCharm?

Tags: git, github, pycharm

Using PyCharm, I am trying to push commit to repo located in my own organisation.

I did the following steps:

1. Cloned an empty repo from github
2. Added and committed all necessary files
3. Tried to push the commit

Before pushing PyCharm asked me to log into my GitHub account. I did it, however I got this error:

```
remote: Permission to <my_org>/<my_repo>.git denied to S1riyS.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<my_org>/<my_repo>.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 0):

After couple of tries to log into GitHub via my account I decided to try token instead and it solved my issue.